# Initialize Angular 2 component with attribute

Tags: angular

Is there any way to pas parameters to the root of an Angular 2 Component? I have been able to do this with the components that are part of the internal component template but not with the root component:

```
<my-component [test] = "some-val"></my-component>
```

On my component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    test: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.test); //test is undefined
    }
}
```

The reason to do this is use Razor variables to be pass to Angular. Like editing a user for instance. I could do something like:

```
<edit-form [model] = "@Model.Id" > </edit-form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular does not do any binding from `index.html` only from within other components.

A workaround to get attribute values in the root component is

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(elementRef:ElementRef) {
    console.log(elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('inputField));
  }
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858