# Injecting data into root component

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular2 (and angular overall) and I'm trying to envision how to integrate angular components with a legacy java app. I'm trying to build a transition path to a SPA like experience, and that means for some time I need to blend the tech stacks.

Specifically, I'm wondering if I were to include a root angular 2 component on a page how I could inject a static JavaScript object into it to (as opposed to building a back end api to serve that data).

For example, I envision something like:

```
<body>
    <my-app [appContext]=appContext>
<\body>
```

I know that can't work, but I'm not sure how else to ask. I think during that app loading phase when we bind the angular component to the  dom element we might be able to inject a JavaScript object into the my-app class. Either that or perhaps the my-app class can access a globally scoped JavaScript object that's declared outside of angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Initialize Angular 2 component with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155082/initialize-angular-2-component-with-attribute/37155204#37155204)
- you can assign the value to a global property `window.appContext` and read it from within Angular2 or pass it as provider
- [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614)

Comment: Thanks. I'm feeling a bit dumb here - trying to use the first approach and finding that elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("appCtxt") is null. In my index.html I have <div id="appCtxt"> some context  </div>. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Perhaps in a Plunker

Comment: For some reason plunker was struggling with adding the ElementRef... here's my github for the sandbox i created: https://github.com/patrickkee/angular2-sandbox

Comment: Worked fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/OdDAdvbRoebfKhEvDcic?p=preview

Comment: Nevermind i got it: i didnt know to do this: <my-app someattribute="somevalue"></my-app>

Comment: This seems so trivial but now I don't know how to make "somevalue" a javascript object rather than a string literal. Can it do that or can i only pass text in? Must I pass a json string in and load it into a javascript object? I want to define a global javascript object and pass that in...

Comment: Attributes only support strings. I guess you can use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Hmmk. I guess now I'll try pulling in a global js variable.

Comment: Would you mind providing more info on how to access a global js variable from window.appContext within angular2?

Comment: Does `console.log(window.appContext);` not work for you? You need to ensure the varible is set before Angular loads otherwise it might not yet be available when you try to read it.

Comment: Well, i found this plunker which looks like a decent implementation but I haven't gotten it working locally yet. http://plnkr.co/edit/ceuEBlVpWhNNYZvMOqbO?p=preview