# Angular2 property binding with ComponentFactoryResolver

Tags: angular, property-binding

I'm trying to bootstrap multiple angular2 components in one HTML page.

```
  <body>
    <cart id="cart">Loading CartComponent content here ...</cart>
    <p>The text between components</p>
    <item [itemId]="1" [itemName]="Cool Item1" id="item-1">Loading ItemComponent id=1 content here ...</item>
    <p>The text between components</p>
    <item [itemId]="2" [itemName]="Cool Item2" id="item-2">Loading ItemComponent id=2 content here ...</item>
    <p>The text between components</p>
    <item [itemId]="3" [itemName]="Cool Item3" id="item-3">Loading ItemComponent id=3 content here ...</item>

  </body>
```

So far everything works fine except property binding of properties that are passed in index.html from a server.

Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/5DbVda?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding on the root element tag are generally not supported in Angular2.

You can work around using

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(elementRef:ElementRef) {
    console.log(elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('inputField));
  }
}
```

See also [Initialize Angular 2 component with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155082/initialize-angular-2-component-with-attribute/37155204#37155204)